# Tableau visualization - Performance issue with huge data

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet, amazon-athena

I have huge data from different DB sources ( Oracle, Mongo, Cassandra ) and also eventing data available in Kafka. Using Tableau for analytics and facing performance issue with huge data. So, planning to store data in some other way and use Tableau for visualization also. Have multiple  options now and need some help to finalize the approach.

**Option 1:-**

Read DB data and store them in Parquet file and then expose it over Spark SQL or HiveQL or Presto SQL and let Tableau connect to this SQL.

**Option 2:-**

Read DB data and store them in Parquet file in S3 and then use AWS Athena for analytics and let Tableau connect to Athena.

**Option 3:-**

Read DB data and store them in Parquet file in S3 and then move to Redshift for analytics and let Tableau connect to Redshift.

Not sure if any of the above approach will be a good solution for streaming data( Kafka ) analytics as well.

Note:- I have multiple big tables and need joins b/w them.

Comment: Another option to try is to store the file in Hyper format instead of Parquet. See the Hyper API on Tableau’s web site

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have huge data from different sources, and you also have access to AWS. Then, you plan to use this data for analytics and dashboarding via Tableau.

### Option 1 and 2

Your Options 1 and 2 are basically the same, as AWS Athena and Hive are based on the same principle of creating tables over flat files via a metastore which stores table definition. Both Athena's Presto engine and Spark are distributed and highly efficient on huge data (TB data). The main difference is the pricing model (Athena is based on price per data processed per request and is serverless, whereas Spark may imply infrastructure cost).

Then, both options may not perform well as they are not OLAP systems designed for self service BI (they are better use for ad hoc queries over huge data regarding).

Then, you may have trouble in managing your data model using flat files and table or views over them (data storage and compression won't be optimized for each table which may impact Tableau performance).

### Option 3

Option 3 is better as it is based on Redshift which is designed to support OLAP system. You can connect Tableau directly to Redshift but you'll suffer from latency and you may have trouble managing your cluster load depending on the number of users and/or requests. But it can work the way you describe it.

Then, if you have performance issues, you'll be able to create data source extracts from Redshift to Tableau later on. You can also implement an intermediate database to store pre-aggregated queries (= datamarts) and connect Tableau directly to it which will avoid performing the same query on Redshift each time a dashboard is opened in Tableau (in that case Redshift also caches queries).

Then, as you need to perform multiple joins, you'll be able to optimize data storage for such queries using Redshift by setting the right partition and sort keys.

To conclude, you can also directly access flat files from Redshift using Redshift Spectrum (via Athena/Glue metastore).

Documentations:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/best-practices.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/fr/athena/pricing/